# Find position of multiple draggable elements

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

How would i be able to find the top, left, bottom and right position of multiple moveable elements on a page? I tried jQuery .position() for it, however the function gives me the position of only the most recent moveable element created (div). Here's the code -

Finding Position -

```
  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
   var createdWindow = $(nWindow).position();
   var createdWindow_right = $(nWindow).position().left + $(nWindow).width();
   var createdWindow_bottom = $(nWindow).position().top + $(nWindow).height();
   console.log("Top position: " + createdWindow.top + ", Left position: " + createdWindow.left + ", right position: " + createdWindow_right + ", bottom position: " + createdWindow_bottom);
// returns an object with x/y coordinates of the top-left corner of the element
```

});

Div Creation -

```
function windowProperties(containment,x,y,width,height){ //New Window Style and jQuery Functions

$(containment).append('<div id="window'+divCount+'"><p id="para'+divCount+'">Drop Here</p></div>');
nWindow = document.getElementById('window'+divCount);
paragraph = document.getElementById('para'+divCount);
paragraph.style.color = "black";
paragraph.style.fontSize = "20px";
paragraph.style.fontWeight = "bold";
paragraph.style.padding = "10px";
paragraph.style.textAlign = "center";

nWindow.style.width = width+"px"; //680
nWindow.style.position = "absolute";
nWindow.style.height = height+"px";  //294.75
nWindow.style.opacity = "0.5";
nWindow.style.background = "white";
nWindow.style.zIndex = "200";
nWindow.style.top = x+"px";
nWindow.style.left = y+"px";
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Use draggable event property of an element  and send event on drag events.
For Example:-

```
<div draggable = true ondragstart="abc(event)>

//some HTML CODE
</div>

<script>

function abc(event)
{
   console.log(event) // here in this event you get all the data of draggable elements
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $.fn.getPosition = function() {
    var results = $(this).position();
    results.right = results.left + $(this).width();
    results.bottom = results.top + $(this).height();
    return results;
  }

  $(".drag").draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      console.log($(this).attr("id"), $(this).getPosition());
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.cnt {
  width: 340px;
  height: 340px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.drag {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="cnt">
  <div class="drag" id="box-1"></div>
  <div class="drag" id="box-2"></div>
</div>
```

This creates a function that can get you the full position. You can then use that in `stop` callback for a Drag action.

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what i needed! Appreciate you!